# Is there ever an application of branch and bound where FIFO is better than LIFO or LCBB?

Tags: branch-and-bound

I understand the difference between FIFO B&B, LIFO B&B, and LCBB, but I just can't think of why you would possibly want to do FIFO since it results in a breadth-first search instead of depth first.   After all, if you can quickly find a better solution and update your BSSF, you can also prune more--so FIFO should generate way more states than, and be slower than, LCBB.  And since the purpose of branch and bound is to find the optimal solution, I don't see why you would ever want the extra states.

Is my thinking correct?  Isn't LCBB always better than FIFO branch and bound?